# How do I limit the clicks numbers to 9?

Tags: jquery

I created a lock that opens when you click "777" and I want to limit the clicks to 9. How do I do that?

```
var numberOfClicks1 = 0; 
var numberOfClicks2 = 0; 
var numberOfClicks3 = 0;

$('#clickme1').on('click', function() {
    numberOfClicks1++; 
    $('#click-counter1').html(numberOfClicks1);
})
$('#clickme2').on('click', function() {
    numberOfClicks2++;
    $('#click-counter2').html(numberOfClicks2);
})
$('#clickme3').on('click', function() {
    numberOfClicks3++;
    $('#click-counter3').html(numberOfClicks3);
})
$('#down-click1').on('click', function() {
    numberOfClicks1--;
    $('#click-counter1').html(numberOfClicks1);
})
$('#down-click2').on('click', function() {
    numberOfClicks2--;
    $('#click-counter2').html(numberOfClicks2);
})
$('#down-click3').on('click', function() {
    numberOfClicks3--;
    $('#click-counter3').html(numberOfClicks3);
})
```

Comment: if you limit the clicks to 9 they wont ever be able to get to 777 assuming you start at 111

Comment: Give us your HTML markup.

Comment: Set a hidden field for "count" the clicks... or a js var

Comment: Do you really want to limit the clicks or do you want to ensure that the values of `numberOfClicks` area always in the range of `1` to `9`

Comment: yes t.niese u got me right i want to ensure that the values of numberOfClicks area always in the range of 1 to 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am guessing right you have three fields that show the number and a +/- for each of the fields. You can just exit the function if your criteria is met:

```
$('#clickme1').on('click', function() {
    if (numberOfClicks1 >= 9) {
        return true;
    }
    numberOfClicks1++; 
    $('#click-counter1').html(numberOfClicks1);
})
```

Comment: Thank you DKsan, very much your answer was much hellpful thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var numberOfClicks1 = 0;
var numberOfClicks2 = 0;
var numberOfClicks3 = 0;

$('#clickme1').on('click', function () {
    if (numberOfClicks1 < 9) {
        numberOfClicks1++;
        $('#click-counter1').html(numberOfClicks1);
    }
})
$('#clickme2').on('click', function () {
    if (numberOfClicks2 < 9) {
        numberOfClicks2++;
        $('#click-counter2').html(numberOfClicks2);
    }
})
$('#clickme3').on('click', function () {
    if (numberOfClicks3 < 9) {
        numberOfClicks3++;
        $('#click-counter3').html(numberOfClicks3);
    }
})
$('#down-click1').on('click', function () {
    if (numberOfClicks1 > 0) {
        numberOfClicks1--;
        $('#click-counter1').html(numberOfClicks1);
    }
})
$('#down-click2').on('click', function () {
    if (numberOfClicks2 > 0) {
        numberOfClicks2--;
        $('#click-counter2').html(numberOfClicks2);
    }
})
$('#down-click3').on('click', function () {
    if (numberOfClicks3 > 0) {
        numberOfClicks3--;
        $('#click-counter3').html(numberOfClicks3);
    }
})
```

Seems i misunderstood your question. The edited code will now limit your `numberOfClicks` variables to be within the range 0-9

Comment: This is most likely wrong, because `#down-...` are `numberOfClicks...--;`, so it should be `if (numberOfClicks... > 1) {` at these places.

Comment: my code was based on the assumption that the OP wanted to limit the amount of times the user changed the variable rather than limit the range. `numberOfClicks` was ++ in my code for all click event handlers

Answer (score 0):

you coud just use a if():

```
$('#clickme1').on('click', function() {
    if(numberOfClicks1<9){
       numberOfClicks1++; 
       $('#click-counter1').html(numberOfClicks1); 
    } else {
       alert("no more clicks");
    }    
})
```

to prevent falling under 0:

```
$('#down-click1').on('click', function() {
    if(numberOfClicks1<0){
        numberOfClicks1--;
        $('#click-counter1').html(numberOfClicks1);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('[id^="clickme"]').on('click', function () {
    var id = $('#click-counter' + this.id.match(/\d+/));
    var num = parseInt(id.text());
    num == 9 ? 9 : num++;
    $(id).text(num);
    var checkLock = $('[id^=click-counter]').map(function () {
        return this.textContent
    });
    if (checkLock[0] == "7" && checkLock[1] == "7" && checkLock[2] == "7") {
        alert("opened");
    }
});

$('[id^="down-click"]').on('click', function () {
    var id = $('#click-counter' + this.id.match(/\d+/));
    var num = parseInt(id.text());
    num == 0 ? 0 : num--;
    $(id).text(num);
    var checkLock = $('[id^=click-counter]').map(function () {
        return this.textContent
    });
    if (checkLock[0] == "7" && checkLock[1] == "7" && checkLock[2] == "7") {
        alert("opened");
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h5eHu/2/)

Comment: Why do you write `$(id)` in this case? `id` is already a jQuery result set there so `id.text(num);` is already working. Also `parseInt($('#click-counter' + this.id.match(/\d+/)).text());` could be written as `parseInt(id.text());`  and you should always specify a radix.

Comment: I didn't wrote `parseInt(this.id)`, i wrote `parseInt(id.text())`.

Comment: @t.niese you are correct, was writing this as fast as possible :)

Comment: `this.textContent` should probably be `$(this).text()`  if IE 8 and IE 7  also should be supported.  And if you want to write shortcuts like `num == 9 ? 9 : num++;` i would suggest to write `num == 9 || num++` because this is a more common pattern. (`? 9` does not carry any additional information, because there is no assignment)